# How do I set up a OneToMany relationship in typeorm?

Tags: mysql, typescript, typeorm

I have a user entity that has as a data member an array of userRoles. The users are stored in the database in a table called users, and the user_roles are stored in a table called user_role_mapping. I want to set up a one to many relationship with typeorm so that when I save a user in the database it also saves the corresponding userRoles in their respective table. I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here is my User entity

```
@Entity("users",{schema:"Cellphones" } )
@Index("net_id",["netId",],{unique:true})
export class User {

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        type:"int", 
        name:"id"
        })
    id: number;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:false,
        unique: true,
        length:20,
        name:"net_id"
        })
    netId: string;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:true,
        length:20,
        name:"employee_id"
        })
    employeeId: string | null;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:false,
        length:50,
        name:"first_name"
        })
    firstName: string;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:false,
        length:50,
        name:"last_name"
        })
    lastName: string;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:true,
        length:50,
        name:"title"
        })
    title: string | null;


    @Column("tinyint",{ 
        nullable:false,
        width:1,
        name:"active"
        })
    active: boolean;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:true,
        length:100,
        name:"email"
        })
    email: string | null;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:true,
        length:20,
        name:"phone"
        })
    phone: string | null;


    @Column("date",{ 
        nullable:true,
        name:"term_date"
        })
    termDate: Date | null;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:true,
        length:10,
        name:"term_department"
        })
    termDepartment:string | null;


    @Column("date",{ 
        nullable:true,
        name:"retire_date"
        })
    retireDate: Date | null;


    @Column("date",{ 
        nullable:false,
        name:"last_login"
        })
    lastLogin: Date;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:false,
        length:50,
        name:"employee_status"
        })
    employeeStatus:string;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:false,
        length:50,
        name:"department"
        })
    department:string;


    @Column("varchar",{ 
        nullable:true,
        length:10,
        name:"pay_group"
        })
    payGroup:string | null;


    @Column("datetime",{ 
        nullable:true,
        name:"updated"
        })
    updated:Date | null;


    @Column("int",{ 
        nullable:true,
        name:"updated_by"
        })
    updatedBy:number | null;


    @Column("date",{ 
        nullable:true,
        name:"inactivated"
        })
    inactivated:Date | null;


    @Column("int",{ 
        nullable:true,
        name:"inactivated_by"
        })
    inactivatedBy:number | null;

    @OneToMany(type => UserRoleMapping, userRoleMapping => userRoleMapping.userId)
    userRoles: UserRoleMapping[];
}
```

Here is my UserRoleMapping entity:

```
@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.userRoles)
@Entity("user_role_mapping",{schema:"Cellphones" } )
export class UserRoleMapping {

    constructor(id: number, userId: number, roleId: number) {}

    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({
        type:"int",
        name:"id"
        })
    id: number;


    @Column({
        type:"int",
        name:"user_id"
        })
    userId: number;

    @Column({
        type:"int",
        name:"role_id"
        })
    roleId: number;
}
```

Here is what the users table looks like:

[image]

Here is what the user_role_mapping table looks like:

[image]

Note that any column with a name starting with old_ is just used for data migration purposes and isn't relevant to this project.

Answer (score 0):

There are some failures in the definition of the entity `UserRoleMapping`:

- A [relation decorater](https://typeorm.io/#/many-to-one-one-to-many-relations) must be applied to entity properties (database columns) not at the class level.
- The inverse property of the relation decorator should not target the primary key of the other table, but the navigation property (which will later hold the mapped entity object not the foreign key).
- The `schema` option of `@Entity` will be ignored if using a mysql database (rather a hint).

If you prefer a [custom naming strategy](https://typeorm.io/#/naming-strategy/) for columns and tables that differ from the entity property names, it can be defined globally in the TypeORM config. For minor adjustments you can derive from [DefaultNamingStrategy](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/naming-strategy/DefaultNamingStrategy.ts).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by navigation property? Do I need to change one of the columns in the database to be a foreign key or something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't tag you ^^

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that makes the relation work.

In User:

```
@OneToMany(type => UserRoleMapping, userRoleMapping => userRoleMapping.user, 
    { eager: true, cascade: true})
userRoles: UserRoleMapping[];
```

In UserRoleMapping:

```
@ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.userRoles)
@JoinColumn({ name: "user_id", referencedColumnName: "id"})
user: User;
```

The key was moving the relation decorator to the user field and defining the @JoinColumn.